# Understanding \$ j \omega \$ axis in transfer function

Tags: transfer-function

I understand the transfer function up to the point of \$ H(\omega) = \lvert H(\omega) \rvert \angle H(\omega) \$ where the magnitude and phase are decoupled into two separate functions, equivalent of saying \$ H(\omega) = { Y_0 \over X_0} \cdot e^{j(\angle y- \angle x \; \text {in radian})}  \$.  I can understand this in polar equation on the complex plan.

Then all of a sudden the transfer function jumps into \$ H(j\omega) = \lvert H(j\omega) \rvert \angle H(j\omega) \$ swapping every \$ \omega \$ with \$ j\omega \$. I'm lost. I searched here and there but I found no explanation on how and why \$ j \$ axis is transformed into \$ j\omega \$ axis, or why \$ j\omega \$ axis is added to the complex plane as a third axis if it's a different axis.

- Does \$ j\omega \$ axis mean \$ j \$ axis multiplied by a frequency magnitude of \$ \omega  \$? If so what does it mean and why an axis has a magnitude? That make no sense to me whatsoever to give magnitude to an axis as axis should only be directional (imagine if someone ask me to graph a line on the x-2y axis instead of a x-y axis)
- Or, is \$ j\omega \$ an entirely different axis from \$ j \$ axis - meaning a number on \$ j\omega \$ axis has no relation to a number on \$ j \$ axis? If that's the case could someone help explain what are their difference and when should I use which?
- Since \$ \omega \$ is the angular velocity, could \$ j \omega \$ represent the rotational axis, a third axis that is orthogonal to \$ j \$ axis and the real axis like a cross product sort of thing?

**[EDIT]**

Just to clarify my thought process here. If I have 2D plane with two axis, x and y, I can define a value \$ z = ax + by \$, where a is a position on the x-axis and b is a position on the y-axis. We can call the value z on the x,y plane. We are not going to call it x,by or x,\$ \omega y\$ plane.

Same logic goes here where the complex frequency s is a value on \$ \sigma \$ or real axis and on \$ j \$ imaginary axis. So a value of s is \$ s = a\sigma + bj\$, where a and b are positions on the real and imaginary axis. So s is on \$ \sigma,j \$ plane, not \$ \sigma,\omega j \$ plane. What is \$ j \omega \$ axis?

Comment: It is only (abuse of) notation. H is a function of omega. Since omega "always" come paired with a `j` as mentioned in the answer, some sources write H as a function of `jw`. Other than this notation difference, you will notice that the actual expressions are same in all the sources.

Comment: @AJN why \$ \omega \$ always come paired with \$ j \$? An \$ j \$ frequency is sine and a real / non-\$ j \$ frequency is cosine.  If my \$ \omega \$ frequency only has cosine, then I could have \$ \sigma \omega \$ instead of \$ j \omega \$?

Comment: You may be confusing the `s` variable concept with the concept of phasors where horizontal axis represents cosine and vertical axis the sine (or cosine). Or the concept of Fourier series where the complex coefficient \$c_n\$ has real part made from coefficient of cosine and imaginary part from coefficient of sine. The concept used here is different. $$\cos(\omega t) = \frac{1}{2} (\exp(j \omega t) + \exp(-j \omega t))$$ and $$\sin(\omega t) = \frac{1}{2j} (\exp(j \omega t) - \exp(-j \omega t))$$ Can you provide sources to the claim "*j frequency is sine and a real / non-j frequency ...*"

Comment: @AJN as for the source, that's how the Euler's formula is defined \$ e^{j\theta} = cos(\theta) + jsin(\theta) \$. If a frequency is even (or cosine) then the frequency only has a real part and the imaginary part (sine or j) must be zero.  If \$ sin(\omega t) = {1 \over {2j}}(exp(j \omega t) − exp(− j \omega t)) \$ then is this on j axis or j \$ \omega \$ axis?

Comment: What I quoted is also just a rearranged version of Euler's formula. AFAIK, there are no separate omega and j.omega axes. It the same axis; just different notation, to my knowledge. The existing answer has some details.

Comment: @AJN, frankly the existing answer provides little insight to my question.  The notation used here is confusing so let me rewrite the equation precisely to be \$ s = \sigma \hat {\sigma} + \omega \hat {j} \$ where \$ \hat {\sigma} \$ and \$ \hat {j} \$ are the orthogonal unit vectors and \$ \sigma \$ and \$ \omega \$ are values on the axis.  But here we transform \$ \hat {j} \$ axis to \$ \hat {j \omega} \$, then we end up with \$ s = \sigma \hat {\sigma} + \omega \hat {j \omega} \$?

Comment: No. An \$\omega j \omega\$ term with two \$\omega\$ doesn't arise. You might as well imagine that the `j` is absent in the notation `H(jw)`. Only reason I can currently think of as to why books use the `H(jw)` notation is probably to distinguish it from \$H(e^{j\omega})\$ that we may encounter in discrete time systems.

Comment: "*Then all of a sudden the transfer function jumps into H(jω)=|H(jω)|∠H(jω) swapping every ω with jω.*" Can you provide a link or a photo where this happens (within the **same** book / website) ?

Comment: @KMC See if [this short video](https://youtu.be/E6R2XUEyRy0) by Brian Douglas helps.

Comment: @relayman357 I've discovered his videos few days back and in fact that was one of the sources that leads me to this question. The video starts with this \$ H(j \omega) = - {1 \over \omega} j \$.  H is a function of a thing called \$ j \omega \$ but the function itself breaks \$ j \omega \$ apart with \$ j \$ in the numerator and \$ \omega \$ in the denominator.  I understand there's this frequency \$ -1 \over \omega \$ with a phase rotated fully onto the imaginary axis by \$ j \$, hence giving \$ sin(\omega t) \$ signal. But again, what the heck is this \$ j \omega \$??

Comment: @KMC complex numbers are not vectors. There is no \$\hat{\j}\$ or \$\hat{\sigma}\$. The reason to write the transfer function in terms of \$j\omega\$ is just to emphasize that the frequency domain is a subset of the \$s\$ domain.

Comment: It's not 'j axis' it's 'w axis' cz w is what is changing on that axis. 'j' doesn't change, its a mathematical constant square root of one. 'j' just denotes w is an imaginary component of the complex number formed with sigma on x-axis.

Answer (score 2):

We start with
$$H(s)$$
in the [frequency domain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-plane), and since $$s =\sigma+j\omega$$
We can replace s with
$$H(\sigma+j\omega)$$
But, in steady state the real part (sigma) is zero, so we get,

$$H(j\omega)$$

To clarify the "transient" (sigma) vs. "steady-state" (omega) , here is damped cosine,
$$h(t)=e^{-0.8t}cos(5t)$$
[image]

Re-writing with only exponentials (using [euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#relationship_to_trigonometry)),
$$h(t)=e^{-0.8t}(\frac{e^{j5t}+e^{-j5t}}{2})$$

Here you can see the exponential with the real value (-0.8) is the transient influence, and those with the imaginary (j5 and -j5) are steady-state.  In this case the steady-state settles out to zero, so i'll give another example that does not.

Let,
$$f(t)=e^{-0.8t}cos(5t)-cos(5t)$$

[image]

Re-writing with all exponentials,

$$f(t)=e^{-0.8t}(\frac{e^{j5t}+e^{-j5t}}{2})-(\frac{e^{j5t}+e^{-j5t}}{2})$$

For completeness, here are the Laplace transforms of the above two time functions h(t) and f(t),

$$\mathcal{L}[h(t)]=H(s)=\frac{s+0.8}{s^2+1.6s+25.64}$$

and,

$$\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=F(s)=\frac{0.8s^2+0.64s-20}{(s^2+25)(s^2+1.6s+25.64)}$$

and now they are in the s-domain and you can analyze them with frequency domain tools/methods.

Comment: Why in steady state the real part (sigma) is zero and why  is attached to or multiplied with ? And my question was why \$ s = \sigma + j \omega \$? If s is a complex plane between real and imaginary, then that should be \$ s = \sigma + j \$, not \$ s = \sigma + j \omega \$. And if we were to multiply \$ \omega \$ to the function, shouldn't we have \$ \omega s = \omega \sigma + j \omega \$?

Comment: @KMC the sigma part is already scaled by omega implicitly. Look at the 3D picture I put in my answer to your previous question; sigma = zeta x omega_n. Dunno if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Andyaka I can't understand anything from the answers on my previous question so I went on reading Fourier analysis and intro control systems behind these answers but the abstraction/notations are absolutely confusing hence this question.  I don't understand what \$ \zeta \$ means and I couldn't find tutorials online explaining what \$ \zeta \$ is on a Bode plot. But here I first want to figure what \$ j \omega \$ axis is and perhaps I could figure out the \$ \zeta \$ myself.

Comment: I am sympathetic; we learn about spectrum analysers and use them but refer to the x axis in terms of Hz or rads/sec then, out of the blue, for bode plots we plug a j in front of frequency. Yet, that's the only bloody axis that is real AND gets a "j" in front of it and, the axis that doesn't exist in reality is left without a "j". It's the maths. At what point did we forget about the real world we exist in LOL